# Grub does not show when booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

now that I finished deleting the other OS since it was a pain of eggs its installation, I have decided to install Ubuntu, it was very easy to install, but, it does not start the grub automatically, start Windows 10 instead.

The only way to boot it is by the BIOS

**specs:**

**Type of hard disk volume:** GPT

**Ubuntu Version:** 18.04 LTS

**Type:** UEFI

Comment: I suggest you try the Boot Repair Disk at https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

Comment: There's no other way? my internet is too slow, to tell you that to download Ubuntu I had to tell another person to download it first

Comment: If you can boot the install disk/usb and go into a live session via “Try Ubuntu” you can then install boot repair in the live session. See option 2 here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. That should minimise the size of the download

Comment: Ready After that I?

Comment: Run the software! The GUI has just a couple of very clear buttons. If you need help search Google with “How to use Boot Repair Disk. It does make it possible to output a file that might help further diagnose the problem if your system still will not boot.